# Can I encapsulate or alter UDP length?

Tags: networking, iptables, openwrt, udp

While packet capturing on a game server I noticed my connection is sending a constant stream of UDP packets all of which roughly 64 bytes in length. How can I merge these packets to send a stream of larger packets 128 bytes in length instead, for example? Some clients were sending data over a protocol named GVSP instead of UDP, how can I switch/encapsulate my UDP data to the GVSP protocol and will this allow for larger packets?

Comment: Note that such merging, while possible, would automatically increase latency.

Comment: @grawity But would reduce overhead from the server reconstructing fragmented packets. Some latency isn't an issue, could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: How do you know they're parts of a fragmented packet, and not merely several individual actions or events happening one after another? (Normally fragments would be as large as possible, not as small as possible.)

Comment: @grawity I cannot be entirely sure, but I would assume a large packet consisting of the actions combined would reduce jitter and any packet reordering that may need to be performed. Do you have any references on how to merge the packets / set a UDP min length, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It is the software that determines the size of the packets and the network protocols it uses.
There is no way to change this unless you can modify the software itself.

You can't impose your own preferences on existing traffic...
Well.... Not entirely true... Sort of...
You could if you can install a "man in middle" device between your own computer and the internet and another such a device between the internet and the server on the other end of the connection.
In that case these devices could re-package the traffic in whatever format you like and unpack the original version at the other end.
This is actually the same sort of thing what a VPN does.

Comment: Do you have any idea why a couple of clients were using GVSP instead of UDP, does this have anything to do with IPv6? Also, when does a router tell the UDP packet to leave the network, is this when the buffer queues are full, and is there any way to speed up the sending time of individual UDP packets in Linux? How about fragmenting to halve the size of the UDP packets is this possible with MITM?